# Открытие формы

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь сделать открытие второй формы, при клике на кнопку.

```
            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();
            Form1.close();
```

Вторая открывается и тут же закрывается.

Comment: А что значит Form1.close()? Какую вы форму закрываете? И можно предоставить код второй формы?

Comment: У второй вообще нет кода. Просто пустая форма. Первая форма Form1, вторая Form2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код открытия второй формы. Этот код располагается в обработке события нажатия кнопки.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
this.Hide();
form2.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

Вторая форма откроется, а первая спрячется. Как только закроется вторая - первая покажется.

Comment: А как сделать, что бы закрылась первая и открылась вторая

Comment: Это будет достаточно сложно. Может вы лучше объясните задачу и я постараюсь предложить другой вариант.

Comment: При клике на кнопку открывается Form2, закрывается Form1 (на ней кнопка)

Comment: Просто так закрыть форму нельзя, так как первая форма является родительской для второй. Но можно скрыть. Я обновил отчет.